# External Content Library - Managing subfolders

Tags: 2013-sp1, ecl

I'm developing my first ECL provider.
We have to connect to a custom-made image repository.

The structure that we defined is:

- In the first access, I retrieve a list of countries. For each country I have to show a folder in the Tridion Gui.
- When I select a folder, I access again and I get a list of cities. For each city I have to show a folder in the Tridion Gui.
- Finally, when the user selects a city folder, I use another ws to get all the images of these city.

Then, we defined in our provider three classes:

- `BrandCenterCountryListItem` that implements `IContentLibraryListItem`.
- `BrandCenterCityListItem` that implements `IContentLibraryListItem`.
- `BrandCenterImage` that implements `BrandCenterHotelListItem`, `IContentLibraryMultimediaItem`.

When I click on the ECL icon I get a list of Countries and I can see all the folders (The Method `GetFolderContent(..)` is executed in my MountPoint class), but when I click in one country(folder) the method executed is `GetItem(..)`.
I expect that the method executed was `GetFolderContent(..)` again, because all the objects created in the first execution were folders.

This is my Types:

```
    public IList<IDisplayType> DisplayTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<IDisplayType>
            {
                HostServices.CreateDisplayType("bccf", "Countries", EclItemTypes.Folder),
                HostServices.CreateDisplayType("bctf", "Cities", EclItemTypes.Folder),
                HostServices.CreateDisplayType("bci", "BrandCenter Image", EclItemTypes.File)
            };
        }
    }
```

And This is my LibraryContext:

using Indra.Tridion.ECL.BrandCenter.BrandCenter.Service.Client.CitiesList;
using Indra.Tridion.ECL.BrandCenter.BrandCenter.Service.Client.CountriesList;
using Indra.Tridion.ECL.BrandCenter.BrandCenter.Service.Client.HotelImages;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.V2;

namespace Indra.Tridion.ECL.BrandCenter
{
    public class BrandCenterMountPoint : IContentLibraryContext
    {
        Dictionary countries = new Dictionary();
        Dictionary cities = new Dictionary();

```
    public bool CanGetUploadMultimediaItemsUrl(int publicationId)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public bool CanSearch(int publicationId)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public IList<IContentLibraryListItem> FindItem(IEclUri eclUri)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public IFolderContent GetFolderContent(IEclUri parentFolderUri, int pageIndex, EclItemTypes itemTypes)
    {
        var items = new List<IContentLibraryListItem>();
        if (parentFolderUri.ItemType == EclItemTypes.MountPoint && itemTypes.HasFlag(EclItemTypes.Folder))
        {
            requestCountries req = new requestCountries();
            req.initial = 0;
            req.number = 100;
            CountriesList cs = BrandCenterProvider.ClientCountriesList.getCountries(req);
            foreach(Country country in cs.countries){
                BrandCenterCountryListItem c = new BrandCenterCountryListItem(parentFolderUri.PublicationId, country);
                countries.Add(country.id.ToString(), c);
            }

            items.AddRange(countries.Values);
        }

        if (parentFolderUri.ItemType == EclItemTypes.Folder && itemTypes.HasFlag(EclItemTypes.File))
        {
            if(parentFolderUri.SubType == "bccf"){
                requestCities req = new requestCities();
                req.initial = 0;
                req.number = 100; 
                CitiesList cs = BrandCenterProvider.ClientCitiesList.getCities(req);
            foreach(City city in cs.cities){
                BrandCenterCityListItem c = new BrandCenterCityListItem(parentFolderUri.PublicationId, city);
                cities.Add(city.id.ToString(), c);
            }

            items.AddRange(cities.Values);
            }
            if (parentFolderUri.SubType == "bctf")
            {
                requestHotels req = new requestHotels();
                req.initial = 0;
                req.number = 100; 
                HotelsList cs = BrandCenterProvider.ClientHotelsList.getHotels(req);
                foreach (Hotel c in cs.hotels)
                {
                    items.Add(new BrandCenterHotelListItem(parentFolderUri.PublicationId, c));
                }
            }
            if (parentFolderUri.SubType == "bchf")
            {

                requestImageHotels req = new requestImageHotels();
                req.initial = 0;
                req.number = 100; 
                ImageHotelsList cs = BrandCenterProvider.ClientImagesHotels.getImageHotels(req);
                foreach (ImageHot c in cs.hotels)
                {
                    items.Add(new BrandCenterImage(parentFolderUri.PublicationId, c));
                }
            }
        }


        return BrandCenterProvider.HostServices.CreateFolderContent(parentFolderUri, items,
            CanGetUploadMultimediaItemsUrl(parentFolderUri.PublicationId), CanSearch(parentFolderUri.PublicationId));
    }

    public IContentLibraryItem GetItem(IEclUri eclUri)
    {
            if(eclUri.SubType == "bccf"){
 //               return countries[eclUri.ItemId];
                }



        if (eclUri.ItemType == EclItemTypes.File && eclUri.SubType == "bci")
        {
     //       return new BrandCenterImage(eclUri.PublicationId, BrandCenterProvider.GetVideo(eclUri.ItemId));
            return null;
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public IList<IContentLibraryItem> GetItems(IList<IEclUri> eclUris)
    {
        var result = new List<IContentLibraryItem>();

        var ids = eclUris.Where(u => u.ItemType == EclItemTypes.File && u.SubType == "bci")
                         .Select(uri => uri.ItemId).Distinct();

        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            var uris = eclUris.Where(u => u.ItemType == EclItemTypes.File && u.SubType == "bci" && u.ItemId == id);
            result.AddRange(uris.Select(GetItem));
        }

        return result;
    }

    public byte[] GetThumbnailImage(IEclUri eclUri, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
    {
      /*  if (eclUri.ItemType == EclItemTypes.File && eclUri.SubType == "bci")
        {
            var video = BrandCenterProvider.Client.GetVideo(eclUri.ItemId);

            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                var data = webClient.DownloadData(video.Thumbnails.FirstOrDefault().Url);
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream(data, false))
                {
                    return BrandCenterProvider.HostServices.CreateThumbnailImage(maxWidth, maxHeight, ms, 600, 600, null);
                }
            }
        }*/

        return null;
    }

    public string GetUploadMultimediaItemsUrl(IEclUri parentFolderUri)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public string GetViewItemUrl(IEclUri eclUri)
    {
        if (eclUri.ItemType == EclItemTypes.File && eclUri.SubType == "bci")
        {
        //    return BrandCenterProvider.Client.GetVideo(eclUri.ItemId).WatchPage.ToString();
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public IFolderContent Search(IEclUri contextUri, string searchTerm, int pageIndex, int numberOfItems)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public void StubComponentCreated(IEclUri eclUri, string tcmUri) {}

    public void StubComponentDeleted(IEclUri eclUri, string tcmUri) {}

    public string IconIdentifier
    {
        get { return ""; }
    }

    public string Dispatch(string command, string payloadVersion, string payload, out string responseVersion)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public void Dispose() {}
}
```

}

But This code has a mix using the part that I'm developing and the youtube example.

What am I missing?

Thank you, Gustavo.

Comment: Can you share some of the code you have in your class implementing the `IContentLibraryContext` interface and what `DisplayTypeId`s you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I've done in my [Flickr ECL Provider](https://github.com/bkoopman/sdl-tridion-world/tree/master/Flickr%20ECL%20Provider/trunk) is make sure that there is a separate class for implementing the `IContentLibraryListItem` interface, which is my [`ListItem` class](https://github.com/bkoopman/sdl-tridion-world/tree/master/Flickr%20ECL%20Provider/trunk).

Then also important is to understand that an ECL folder, is still an ECL item, so it must also implement the `IContentLibraryItem` interface. You can see an example of that in my [`FlickrPhotoSet` class](https://github.com/bkoopman/sdl-tridion-world/blob/master/Flickr%20ECL%20Provider/trunk/Flickr%20ECL%20Provider/FlickrPhotoSet.cs)

The [`ListItem` class](https://github.com/bkoopman/sdl-tridion-world/tree/master/Flickr%20ECL%20Provider/trunk) is basically the prototype of any item I will use, since all items will be displayed in a list (folders and the actual multimedia items).

In my [`Provider` class](https://github.com/bkoopman/sdl-tridion-world/blob/master/Flickr%20ECL%20Provider/trunk/Flickr%20ECL%20Provider/Provider.cs) (implementing the `IContentLibrary` interface) I have defined the different display types so that ECL knows what is a `EclItemTypes.Folder` and what is a `EclItemTypes.File`. Check the `DisplayTypeId` property in the [`ListItem` class](https://github.com/bkoopman/sdl-tridion-world/blob/master/Flickr%20ECL%20Provider/trunk/Flickr%20ECL%20Provider/ListItem.cs).

Comment: Flickr ECL Provider is a perfect reference. Thank you.